# how to trigger a command from another file

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a music bot, but i have an issue with the loop command, I want to trigger loop.js when the user clicks on a certain react emoji on the playing menu, for now, the command runs independently in both play.js and loop.js. The reason I want to do this is because in case a user selects the reaction and then does the command itself, the bot would say the opposite if it was either on or off.

Here is my loop.js

```
module.exports = {
  name: "loop",
  aliases: ['l'],
  description: "Toggle music loop",
  execute(message) {

    const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
    if (!queue) return message.reply("There is nothing playing.").catch(console.error);
    if (!canModifyQueue(message.member)) return;

    let loopembed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Loop settings")
    .setDescription(`Loop is now ${queue.loop ? "**on**" : "**off**"}`)
    .setColor(message.guild.me.displayColor)
    .setFooter(`Action performed by ${message.author.tag}`)

    // toggle from false to true and reverse
    queue.loop = !queue.loop;
    return queue.textChannel
      .send(loopembed)
      .catch(console.error);
  }
};
```

And here is my loop reaction command from play.js

```
        case "":
          reaction.users.remove(user).catch(console.error);
          if (!canModifyQueue(member)) return;
          queue.loop = !queue.loop;
          queue.textChannel.send(`Loop is now ${queue.loop ? "**on**" : "**off**"}`).catch(console.error);
          break;
```

I'm trying to make loop.js run instead of it being run independently in case of the reacted emoji.
Thank you for helping in advance

Comment: If I understood correctly, you could just require loop.js in play.js just as you did on the command handler. And call the execute inside the switch.

Comment: you mean I should delete loop.js and instead move the command to play.js?

Comment: No, I assumed you have a command handler structure similar to the official guide. Anyway, what you can do is have ```const loop = require('./loop.js');``` at the top of play.js (assuming loop.js and play.js are both on the same directory) and before the break of the switch you could call loop.js' execute method as ```loop.execute(message);```.

Comment: After making this change, once the bot is reacted with loop, It executes loop.js but it then proceeds to stop the music queue

Comment: Hm... feel free to edit this question or open another one with a better explanation directed towards this specific problem. I order to seek a solution to this problem, we need more info, but I'm glad I _maybe_ helped you to find a solution to the original question, which is ```how to trigger a command from another file```. Best of luck! = )

Comment: thank you, I too shall try to find a solution to this